# Is there a way to fix window buffer in emacs for cider error/repl

Tags: emacs, configuration, clojure, cider

Using emacs 24.4, with clojure mode and `cider-jack-in`. Anytime I evaluate a wrong exception the error buffer randomly replaces buffers in any other screen splits. Now I am looking for some configuration in init.el which help me to configure something like this:

1. When clojure mode is selected/or I opened a `.clj` file, `cider-jack-in` started by default.
2. The screen should split in 4 parts 1 current buffer/file i opened, 1 more scratch buffer, repl and clojure error msg buffer.

Comment: If you have not already tried setting some of the windows as dedicated, perhaps you could try that:  http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Dedicated-Windows.html  The display buffer family of functions generally looks for a window that is not dedicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have two settings in my init files related to similar requirement:

```
(add-to-list 'same-window-buffer-names "<em>nrepl</em>")
```

same-window-buffer-names is a built-in feature of Emacs.

The other one is a helper function I use that harnesses the sticky-windows extension.

```
;; Toggle window dedication
(defun toggle-window-dedicated ()
  "Toggle whether the current active window is dedicated or not"
  (interactive)
  (message
   (if (let (window (get-buffer-window (current-buffer)))
         (set-window-dedicated-p window
                                 (not (window-dedicated-p window))))
       "Window '%s' is dedicated"
     "Window '%s' is normal")
   (current-buffer)))
```

It's not a full answer to your question, but hopefully a good starting point :)